# Путь к файлу не записывается в URI System.UriFormatException: "Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid."

Tags: c#, wpf, mediaplayer, uri, media

Я пишу программу на C# WPF в Visual Studio Community 2019 используя компонент MediaElement.
Когда я пытаюсь с помощью события изменить источник видеофайла возникает исключение System.UriFormatException: "Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid."
Такое возникает даже тогда, когда я копирую строку с путем к файлу из части, которая выполняется при запуске. При этом при запуске программы видео запускается, а при нажатии кнопки вылезает ошибка, хотя путь идентичный.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string r2 = "D:\\jetix movies\\Jetix Ident.mp4";
        System.Uri uri2 = new Uri(r2);
        Media.Source = uri2;
        Media.Play();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string r2 = "‪D:\\jetix movies\\Jetix Ident.mp4";
        System.Uri uri2 = new Uri(r2);
        Media.Source = uri2;
        Media.Play();
    }
}
```

Вызвано исключение: "System.UriFormatException" в System.Private.Uri.dll
Необработанное исключение типа "System.UriFormatException" в System.Private.Uri.dll
Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не пишите свой код в кострукторе формы, пишите его в обработчике `Window.Loaded`.

Comment: Так схема не указана, вот оно и не понимает, что с этим делать. Допишите. что ли, схему `file:` к своему адресу.

Comment: [File (схема URI)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_(%D1%81%D1%85%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_URI))

Comment: Cпасибо вам большое! Теперь я понял, как надо указывать путь к файлу.

Comment: Странно, у меня всё работает (c) https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYCMBYAUANwEMwACCMASxIF4SoBTAdxIFVKAKAIgBEQAdPgCt6wCgA8SAWwD2+CvQDOAgFIjxJAJJx6UYADpJABwAsnAJQBuPKkwBOduQqWgA==